# Pythonic way to insert character

Tags: python, string

I have two transform cases:

```
s = "foo bar" #-> "foo bar &"
s = "foo ! bar" # -> "foo & ! bar" -> notice not '&!'
```

I did it like this:

```
t = s.split("!", 1)
t[0] = t[0] + "  &"
" !".join(t)
```

What's a more pythonic way to do the same?

Comment: If there are multiple exclamation marks, should it put an ampersand with all of them?

Comment: @Josiah Just first - split is limited to at most 1 split

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "transform cases"?

Comment: @Levon each line/string is transformed differently, depending if `!` is present

Comment: @Anycorn: So, it's like a grammar?

Comment: To make your original code more pythonic change `t[0] = t[0] + "  &"` to `t[0] += "  &"`

Comment: @jamylak i don't think strings are mutable

Comment: Notice that `split()` deletes the character it splits on. According to the earlier part of your question, that's not what you want.

Comment: @Anycorn: He is referring to the list. Yes, strings are not mutable.

Comment: @Anycorn they don't have to be mutable. The inplace assignment performed by `+=` may or may not work but the reference is still changed to the result of the operation at the end.

Comment: @JoelCornett yes, simple fortran parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.partition` is built for the purpose of operator parsing:

```
p = s.partition(' !')
print p[0]+' &'+p[1]+p[2]
```

It is adapted to prefix and infix operator when parsing from left to right. The fact it always returns a 3-tuple allows to use it even when your operator is not found and apply an action on your result as shown above.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is any more pythonic, but the example above can be done as a one-liner.

```
>>> s = "foo ! bar"
>>> s = s.replace(' ! ', ' & ! ') if '!' in s else s + ' &'
>>> s
'foo & ! bar'
```

Comment: I think I like the original more than this.

Comment: more or less what I was thinking.

Comment: That seems more `perlic` (I think the correct version is "gibberish") than `pythonic` to me ;)

Comment: I think this could be made quite a bit more readable just by reversing the condition: `s = s.replace(' ! ', ' & ! ', 1) if '!' in s else s + ' &'`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @lvc, I agree with you and have made the changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'( !|$)', r' &\1', 'foo bar', 1)
'foo bar &'
>>> re.sub(r'( !|$)', r' &\1', 'foo ! bar', 1)
'foo & ! bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing multiple sentences in one line:

```
>>> s = ["foo bar", "foo ! bar"]
>>> [x + ' &' if not '!' in x else x.replace('!','& !', 1) for x in s]
['foo bar &', 'foo & ! bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = "foo bar"
s2 = "foo ! bar"

import re

print re.sub(r'^([^!]+)( |$)', r'\1 &\2', s1) # foo bar &
print re.sub(r'^([^!]+)( |$)', r'\1 &\2', s2) # foo & ! bar
```